# Remove sequential NumPy array index in a loop over it's content

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy, scipy

I'm iterating over a NumPy (nd) array of OpenCV lines. I want to remove all lines which are outwith 8 degrees of vertical. I realise the numpy array is immutable and what I'm doing in the code is not right but it demonstrates the idea of what I'm trying to do;

```
index = 0
for line in self.lines[0]:
    if (line[1]*180)/np.pi > 8:                                      
        self.lines[0] = np.delete(self.lines[0], index, axis=0)
    index+=1
```

How can I go about removing these NumPy array indexes?

Thanks!

Comment: A better explanation of problem is required if you want someone to help you...

Comment: what other information would you like?

Comment: What actually this code line `if (line[1]*180)/np.pi > 8` does, or what are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: it checks whether the line is greater than 8 degrees and if so removes that item from the NumPy array. The question is mainly about removing from a NumPy array or creating a new one without these in it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot delete array indexes while iterating over that array. It will give wrong results. Say you are at iteration 5 and this index satisfies `if` condition and needs to be deleted, but if we delete this it will cause array element at index 6 to come at index 5 and next element selected will be 7 which comes to index 6 after deletion and thus condition is never checked for element initially at index 6 i.e., before deletion.

Basic idea to deal with this issue is to append these indices to a list and delete them outside lope. So your code is:

```
index = 0
idx = []
for line in self.lines[0]:
    if (line[1]*180)/np.pi > 8:     
       idx.append(index)         
    index+=1

self.lines[0] = np.delete(self.lines[0], idx, axis=0)
```

Comment: I get an error with your solution. ValueError: invalid entry

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are missing indentation in your code, so I interpret it like this:

```
index = 0
for line in self.lines[0]:
    if (line[1]*180)/np.pi > 8:                                      
        self.lines[0] = np.delete(self.lines[0], index, axis=0)
    index+=1
```

You can do that of course without a loop. First we do the check to build the [boolean indexing array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) (True/False values for every item in the array):

```
index = self.lines[0,:,1]*180/np.pi > 8
```

Then we select the lines, where the condition is false:

```
a[~a%2==0]
```

Where [`np.nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) converts from a boolean array to an array, where all indices with True-values are listed.

For example:

```
>>> a  = np.arange(10)
>>> a[~a%2==0]
array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
```

Comment: what does your second last line do? not familiar with the syntax

Comment: @MarkCorrigan I added now more explanations, an example and links to the docs. This would be now the way how to achieve your problem in a 'Numpythonic' way.

Comment: That last `delete` could be replaced with boolean indexing: `a[~a%2==0]`.  `delete` is a complex function that always returns a new array.  It does not directly modify its input.